# Why gnome-terminal tells me "There is still a process running" while logged in as root?

Tags: root, gnome-terminal

I'm using gnome on Debian Jessie. When I tried to close terminal after logged in as **root**, it told me like in the picture below.

[image: Terminal Problem]

What should I do to prevent this from happening again? Is it a bug??

Thanks for checking me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well there *are* processess running in your terminal from before you became root -- `sudo` (or `su`) and two `bash` (one for root, one for your normal user)... as well as any background-jobs (started with & or put in the background) in either shell.  It's a fair warning, and it's good if you're about to accidently close a terminal.

If you `exit` root first (which you ought to), you don't get the warning.  Even better, if you also `exit` the shell for your normal user.  Just closing the terminal not only risk killing some running proccess you've forgot about, it also prevents the shell (`bash`) from saving things like command-history.

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong: closing the terminal sends SIGHUP to the shell, and that does make it save the history. If you don't get the warning, then I think there's no larger risk of killing background tasks than when exiting the shell, but I'm not sure, it's possible that the set of processes that receive SIGHUP is different in some corner cases.